# How to make css overlay hidden while having position as absolute

Tags: css

This is my HTML

```
<div id="frame">
  <ol>
    <li><img class="image" src="http://www.placehold.it/80X80" /></li>
  </ol>
</div>​
```

My JsFiddle : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RXr2E/1/)

I want to put the image inside the div so the Div wraps the image with rounded corders? That means I want to have rounded corners on my image while having it as `position:absolute`?

Comment: Wrapping the image around the frame? Thats really strange wording. You would position <div> which wraps the image not the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the `border-radius` attributes to your image class. Assuming I understood your end-goal, that should do what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/cjc343/RXr2E/2/

Comment: Cant. Coz I might have many `li`s and I just want the first and the last image to have rounded corners. Not the ones in the middle.

Comment: Use `first-child` and `last-child` pseudo-selectors: http://jsfiddle.net/cjc343/RXr2E/5/ There is absolutely no way I could have gotten there from your question though. The more you can tell us up-front about what you're trying to do, the easier it is to help you.